# SQlite Foreign Key Violation

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a problem, which is that I'm doing a program that is based on database stored addresses ip's and ip's such records.
I have two tables in the database, one called automata which stores the IP address (key), the company name, and the name you want to put the IP address.

the other table is called records and saves the address records (key), the name of these, the record type and a foreign key to this relaccionada id_ip table with ip automata.

The source(SQLite):

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String CreaSqlAutomata = "CREATE TABLE automata (ip TEXT PRIMARY KEY, empresa TEXT,  nombre TEXT)";
    String CreaSqlRegistro = "CREATE TABLE registro (direccion INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tipo TEXT,  nombreAutomata TEXT, id_ip TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(id_ip) REFERENCES automata(ip))";

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context contexto, String nombre,CursorFactory factory, int version) {
                super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CreaSqlAutomata);
        db.execSQL(CreaSqlRegistro);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_autreg_autip " +
                " BEFORE INSERT "+" ON registro FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+ " SELECT CASE `WHEN ((SELECT ip FROM automata WHERE ip=new.id_ip ) IS NULL)"+`
                        " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END;"+
                " END;");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnte, int versionNue) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS automata");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS registro");
        db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fk_autreg_autip");


        //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
        db.execSQL(CreaSqlAutomata);
        db.execSQL(CreaSqlRegistro);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_autreg_autip " +
                " BEFORE INSERT "+" ON registro FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+ "SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT ip FROM automata WHERE ip=new.id_ip ) IS NULL)"+
                        " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END;"+
                " END;");
    }   
    public class automatas {


        private String nombre;
        private String ip;
        private String empresa;

        // Constructor de un objeto Contactos
        public automatas( String nombre, String ip, String empresa) {

            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.empresa = empresa;
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        // Recuperar/establecer Ip
        public String getIP() {
            return ip;
        }
        public void setIP(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        // Recuperar/establecer NOMBRE
        public String getNOMBRE() {
            return nombre;
        }
        public void setNOMBRE(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        // Recuperar/establecer EMPRESA
        public String getEMPRESA() {
            return empresa;
        }
        public void setEMPRESA(String empresa) {
            this.empresa = empresa;
        }


    }
}
```

What I want is to keep a record which the IP address of the lame automata using a spinner and record the address of the user inserts the problem is is that when I type the IP address of the automaton fails, is not well recognized and do not know why .... I'm desperate!

```
public class guardar_registros extends Activity {
    Spinner spinner1,spinner2;
    EditText nombre,direccion;
    Button boton;
    String basededatos= "BDautomata.db";
    String registro_ip,tipo_registro;
    int i = 0,flag=0;
    Cursor cur;
    String[] lista_ip = new String [20];
    ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> lista;

    List<String> lista_contactos = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.guardar_registros);

         spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoRegistro);
         spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerIP);
         nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NombreRegistro);
         direccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dirRegistro);
         boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarRegistro);

         lista = new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
         lista.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         lista.add("Entero");
         lista.add("Real(1 decimal)");
         lista.add("Real (2 decimales)");
         lista.add("Binario");
         spinner1.setAdapter(lista);
         cur = obtenerIP();
         SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , cur, new String[]{"_id"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },0);
         mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         spinner2.setAdapter(mAdapter);

         spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener2());
         spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener1());

    }

    public Cursor obtenerIP (){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper automata= new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "BDautomata", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = automata.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = bd.rawQuery(" SELECT ip AS _id FROM automata ", null);

        return c;
        }
    public void guardarRegistro(View v)  {

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper automata= new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "BDautomata", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = automata.getWritableDatabase();



        if (bd!=null){
        String nombreRegistro = nombre.getText().toString();
        String direccionR = direccion.getText().toString();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("id_ip", registro_ip);
        cv.put("direccion", direccionR);
        cv.put("nombreAutomata", nombreRegistro);
        cv.put("tipo", tipo_registro);
        bd.insert("registro", "direccion", cv);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Se guardaron los datos del automata",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //comprobamos que funciona

    }else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error al crear la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    // Listener para el spinner2 el cual tiene las ip de los automatas
    public class SpinnerListener2 implements OnItemSelectedListener {


          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
              View view, int pos, long id) {
                   registro_ip=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                   }
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
              //para asegurar que el usuario selecciona una ip
            //flag=0;
          }
      }
    //Listener del Spinner1 el cuel contiene el tipo del registro.
    public class SpinnerListener1 implements OnItemSelectedListener {


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

                 tipo_registro=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                 //flag=1;
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          //para asegurar que el usuario selecciona una ip//flag=0;
        }
    }
}
```

the logcat:

```
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212): Error inserting nombreAutomata=asd id_ip=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40dfbc68 direccion=123 tipo=Entero
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: Foreign Key Violation (code 19)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at com.JR.scada.guardar_registros.guardarRegistro(guardar_registros.java:84)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-24 09:56:42.707: E/SQLiteDatabase(9212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is the actual value of `registro_ip` that you want to insert?

Comment: What I want is inserted into the IP registro_ip that is type string but the problem is that grabs the data well. I debugged and saves resgistro_ip this: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor @ 40dfba18 and do not know why = (

Comment: I do not understand what "grabs the data well" means. And `registro_ip` is a `String`, your "SQLiteCursor" output is not related to that.

Comment: I fixed that was returning a cursor and I treated him like string `Cursor cursor=(SQLiteCursor) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
         registro_ip = cursor.getString(0);
         depuracion.setText(registro_ip);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener1());`                                            fixed this once I get this problem, and it is not the registration table, says no such registration table

Comment: new logcat: `09-25 07:27:45.976: E/SQLiteLog(1151): (1) no such table: registro
09-25 07:27:46.176: E/SQLiteDatabase(1151): Error inserting id_ip=a nombreAutomata=qwer direccion=1234 tipo=Entero
09-25 07:27:46.176: E/SQLiteDatabase(1151): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: registro (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO registro(id_ip,nombreAutomata,direccion,tipo) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`